# Joomla strips jqGrid pagination and sorting params

Tags: jqgrid, joomla

I'm trying to build a project management tool using joomla and jqGrid. I can't code in Joomla so i use the jumi component that allows for custom scripts. I use only one file as entry point and i' ve developed a sort of front controller that dispatches the appropriate action to the appropriate controller.
Thus far the tool works fine except one point. The parameters rows, page, sidx and sord added by jqGrid in the url when asking for data are somehow stripped off by joomla and the values that i get in my script are always null. Has anyone else encountered this problem before?
Thanks in advance

One strange thing i noticed using firebug is that in the params section of firebug all parameters are there. But i cannot fetch the value with $_GET or $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly from your description but usually this is a Mootools conflict.

Use jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Thanks but that's not the problem. I cannot understand whats going on. On Firebug i can see that the $_GET request is correct, the url contains all params, firebug reads all params, the ajax response is correct, but i cannot read half of the params in my script.